# Getting array from JSON object

Tags: javascript, json

I have this JSON object:

```
var Events = {
"Jan" : [],
"Feb" : [],
"Mar" : {
    "23" : [
        {"eventName" : "Start", "eventYear" : 2015, "eventDescription" : "First event description"},
        {"eventName" : "Start 2", "eventYear" : 2016, "eventDescription" : "Second event description"},
        {"eventName" : "Start 3", "eventYear" : 2017, "eventDescription" : "Third event description"}
    ],
    "24" : [
        {"eventName" : "Start", "eventYear" : 2015, "eventDescription" : "First event description for 24"},
        {"eventName" : "Start 2", "eventYear" : 2016, "eventDescription" : "Second event description for 24"}
    ]
},
"Apr" : [],
"May" : [],
"Jun" : [],
"Jul" : [],
"Aug" : [],
"Sep" : [],
"Oct" : [],
"Nov" : [],
"Dec" : []
}
```

I'm trying to get events array for current month:

```
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', init);
var date, month_names_short, thisMonthEvents;
function init(){
    date = new Date();
    month_names_short = ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec'];
    thisMonthEvents = Events.month_names_short[date.getMonth()];
};
```

But I'm getting this error `TypeError: Cannot read property '2' of undefined` for this line:

```
thisMonthEvents = Events.month_names_short[date.getMonth()];
```

What am I doing wrong and how can it be fixed?

Comment: Do you mean `thisMonthEvents = Events[month_names_short[date.getMonth()]]`?

Comment: have you tried using `getJSONArray()` and `setJSONArray()`?

Comment: `month_names_short` is not a property of Events

Comment: @nnnnnn Yup, that's what I needed, thanks! Can you post it as an answer, please, so I could accept it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you need to find month name in `month_names_short` array by index. Then using [bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors#Bracket_notation) and found name you can access corresponding event:

```
function init() {
    date = new Date();
    month_names_short = ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec'];
    thisMonthEvents = Events[month_names_short[date.getMonth()]];
};
```

Answer (score 0):

If you do plan to use the month_names_short array, you can do something like this:

```
function init(){
    date = new Date();
    month_names_short = ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec'];
    for (var index in month_names_short) {
         var month = month_names_short[index];
         thisMonthEvents = Events[month];
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `"[]"` instead of `"." donation`.

```
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', init);
var date, month_names_short, thisMonthEvents;
function init(){
    date = new Date();
    month_names_short = ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec'];
    thisMonthEvents = Events[month_names_short[date.getMonth()]];
};
```